# Is this simplified version of map/lambda in python?

Tags: python

For map/lambda expression with array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`:

```
f = map(lambda x : x + 32, a)
```

Seems I can simplify write as:

```
f = [x + 32 for x in a]
```

I am wondering whether there is any difference.

Comment: if the final goal is to obtain a list with modified values, then there would some speed difference (the 1st case would be `list(map(lambda x : x + 32, a))`)

Comment: [Performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with mapreduce....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda` tends to be slower cause of the function's overhead. Also lambdas tend to make code more difficult to read. You can also time it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

t1 = time.time()
f = map(lambda x : x + 32, a)
t2 = time.time()-t1
print t2

t3 = time.time()
g = [x + 32 for x in a]
t4 = time.time()-t3
print t4
```

This code returned:

```
7.86781311035e-06
2.14576721191e-06
```

Also I tried the same thing for larger lists and the time taken is almost double for `lambda` expression.

```
python -m timeit '[x + 32 for x in range(100000)]'

>> 100 loops, best of 3: 6.67 msec per loop

python -m timeit 'map(lambda x : x + 32, range(100000))'

>> 100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 msec per loop
```

which is huge difference in performance.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran performance is always a big thing to consider. See the metrics above, I like lambdas too but they tend to be slow.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran What is more Pythonic than a list comprehension? And "Readability counts" - a lot!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran but a lambda doesn't divide code into functions, it *uses an anonymous function*.

Comment: @frank this isn't a very good timing comparison. You should really use `timeit`, but more importantly, you are using a very short list, so the majority of your difference is really just the differing overheads of the two approaches.

Comment: @Miraj50 thank you very much!

Comment: Is it slow ? My test showed otherwise
[prateek@localhost pythonista]$ python -mtimeit -s'a=[1,2,3,4]' 'map(lambda x:x+2,a)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.189 usec per loop
[prateek@localhost pythonista]$ python -mtimeit -s'a=[1,2,3,4]' '[x + 32 for x in a]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.291 usec per loop
[prateek@localhost pythonista]

Comment: I get it. I get it. But Lambda is nothing but anonymous functions in python! And as far as the performance is concerned, try running the same code in a for loop. There using map and lambda seems better.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran One can ease one's life (and that of one's co-coders) living by simple rules. Not cluttering a codebase with `lambda`-contaminated `map` and `filter` expressions is one of them ;)

Comment: True. For simpler cases, a simple list comprehension may be more than enough. But what I meant was programming in a bigger scale where performance really matters.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran in my own tests and in the tests you see linked around here tend to show that list-comprehensions are faster, with the exception of mapping built-in functions, e.g. `list(map(float, seq_of_int))`

Comment: @The_Lost_Avatar are you on Python 2? On Python 3, you need `list(map(...))`, anyway, those tests are nearly worthless! `a` has length 4!

Comment: I've tested using both python2 and python3! And, list comprehensions are faster only when the code needs to be executed a few number of times.